# Reverter o git checkout -f

Tags: git

Ao dar um git checkout -f em um arquivo modified é possível recuperar as mudanças perdidas?
Alguma maneira de reverter o git checkout -f

Comment: Acho que [esse link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961240/get-back-the-changes-after-accidental-checkout) pode te ajudar.

Comment: Em resumo: se não foi adicionada no histórico, a mudança não é rastreável pelo git. O link do @WhoisMatt indica um modo para evitar esses erros futuramente, criando diversos _stashes_